# The equation of the normal to the curve.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation of the normal to the curve:
$f(x)=x^2-5$ at $x=2$
I know that $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$
But I don't really know how to procede

Comment: Hint: Compute the point on the curve and the derivative $m$, then the perpendicular line has slope $-1/m$ and passes through the same point.  *Note* in multivariate calculus, the normal has a more precise meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f′(x) = 2x$$
$$f′(2) = 4$$
Tangent is perpendicular to normal, so:
$$m_1*m_2 = -1$$
$$4*m_2=-1$$
$$m_2=\frac{-1}{4}$$
At $x=2$, $y=-1$
So:
$$y-(-1)=\frac{-1}{4}(x-2)$$
$$y+1=\frac{-1}{4}(x-2)$$
$$y=\frac{-1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}-1$$
Equation of normal is:
$$y=-\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{4}(x+2)$$

Comment: Is it y=-1/4(x+2) or y=-1/4(x-2) ?

Comment: the first one is right

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The slope of the tangent line at $x=2$ is $m=f'(2)$ and the slope of the normal is $m'=\dfrac{-1}{m}$.

Comment: So, is the answer  y=(-1/4)(x+2) ?

Comment: That seems to be my answer with my calculations.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.